# How can I compare an array of 6 ints to a 2d array of ints [19][5]?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a project for school and can't figure this out. I'm a very beginning level beginner btw.

I have a 2d array called `tickets[19][6]` 20 tickets with 6 ints in each ticket.
I'm trying to compare those 20 tickets to a regular array of ints with 6 numbers called `winner[5]`, which I read from a .txt file.

both arrays are stated as follows:

```
public static int[] winner = new int[5]
public static int[][] tickets = new int[19][5]
```

Please keep in mind I'm very new to this, and I appreciate any help in advance!

*EDIT* this is the loop I'm using to assign user input to my 2d array, just realized when I went through the whole thing that it was an endless loop. I thought writing code would be more....well, writing! Seems to be more like the art of debugging so far.

```
static void ticketNumberArray(){

    int number = 1;        // which of the six numbers you need from the ticket
    int ticketCount = 1;   // which ticket (out of 20) you are currently on

    while(ticketCount<21){ // sentinel controlled while loop,
                           // will continue until the twentieth ticket is entered
        System.out.println("Please type number " +number+ " of ticket number " +ticketCount+ ".");
                           //asks for the numbers of the ticket your currently on

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // initiates a scanner variable

        int ticketNumber = keyboard.nextInt();     // assigns user input to the double variable ticketNumber
                                                   // and initializes as a double

        tickets[ticketCount-1][number-1]=ticketNumber;  // assigns user input into a 2-d array

        number++;           //Sentinel variable

        if(number==7){      //loop that controls the ticket count, every 6 numbers ='s one ticket
            ticketCount++;
            number=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "compare"?  Test for equality?

Comment: I believe test for equality yes. I'm trying to compare the winner[] to the tickets[][] with the purpose of searching the tickets[][] for a match to winner[]

Comment: You'd use what's known as "iteration" -- `for` loop, eg.  Probably 3 nested loops. (Well, probably 2 loops, nested, on re-reading your problem.)

Comment: 3 nested for loops? Ehh no...

Answer (score 3):

First off, the number you put in the `[ ]` when you declare the array is the size of the array. So, to make an array with six items, you need to put `[6]`. The indexes will be numbered 0-->5.

You just need to loop over the ticket "rows" in the `tickets` array, and compare it to the winner array. Each row is an inviidual ticket. The "columns" in the 2D array would be the individual numbes that comprise the ticket.

You can use Louis's suggestion with `Arrays.equal` if the order of the individual numbers in the ticket matters. (ie. you can only win with ticket `0-1-2-3` if the winner is `0-1-2-3` -- most lotteries allow you to win any combination.)

```
for(int i=0; i < tickets.length; i++)
{
   int[] ticket = tickets[i];

   if(Arrays.equals(ticket, winner))
   {
      // This one is the winner

      // For efficiency you should probably stop looping
      break;
   }
}
```

---

Edit:

A lot of intro professors don't like it when students use the API. So, you'd have to write you own equals function.

```
private static boolean areEqual(int[] a, int[] b)
{ 
   if(a == null && b == null)
       return true;

   // Not equal if one is null and the other is not     
   if(a == null || b == null)
       return false;

   if(a.length != b.length)
       return false;

   // When we get here we have to check each element, one by one
   // Implementation left as exercise :-)
}
```

Comment: mk, so I assume I have to fill a and b in with winner and tickets respectively...I'm not sure what you mean by implementation, however. This looks nothing like any code I've been taught about so far =/

Comment: `areEqual` is a function that is supposed to do the same thing as `Arrays.equals()`. As I said, a lot of professors don't like students making calls to the API. You would just call `areEqual(ticket, winner)` instead of calling the `Arrays...` function. I left the implementation of actually checking the elements in the array (in `areEqual()`) for you to do...

Comment: ok, so I think I can take it from there....I'm also having trouble with assigning user input to the 2d array. I just tried to get all 20 tickets entered and I'm going in an endless loop. Here's what I got. *added loop to original question*

Comment: You can't put long comments on stack overflow. Start a new question for the input problem

Answer (score 1):

Do the tickets have 5 integers, or 6?  Your question contradicts itself.

In any event, if you just want to check if the integers in the tickets match -- if they have exactly the same values in exactly the same order -- the simplest solution is just to use [`Arrays.equals(int[], int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29).

Comment: I've tried that, however, tickets[][] is a 2d array, and it will not compare it with winner[]...I've tried 'deep.equals' but that doesn't work either. =/

Comment: @user1350269: Of course not.  You have to compare a single ticket with `winner`.  So `Arrays.equals(tickets[i], winner)` will tell you if `tickets[i]` is equal to `winner`.

Comment: you know, that actually makes so much sense I can see why I didn't think of it....and I can make a while loop with i as the sentinel to compare all of them....I'm gonna try that real quick. Amazing how fast Replies come in on here!